# Load Table Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is very simple but I cannot find any examples of how it's done anywhere. I created a new ASP Website and have the following code:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="clear_10">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="load_wrapper">
    &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="name_selection_wrapper">
        <p><span>Please enter one of the choices below</span></p>
        <div class="clear_10">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="user_input">
            <input class="input" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        <ul class="name_wrapper">
            <li><span class="dash">-</span>Sue</li>
            <li><span class="dash">-</span>Joe</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_10">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

I created a new database named People with two tables, one for Sue and the other for Joe. Simply put how on earth how do I pass a query to retrieve and display the information from either table in my div load_wrapper.

Comment: Why do Sue and Joe need their own tables?

Comment: Downvoted. This question is far too general and assumes no prior knowledge at all. While everyone needs to start somewhere, you're better off asking "how do I get started with ASP.NET", rather than asking someone to do this all for you. You need to start off with some tutorials, head over to http://asp.net and spend some time there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the data using backend C# code.

Then, you'll have to pass the data to the page.

Either, insert the HTML you generate from the data into the page where required by making a div have the property `runat='server'` and giving it an ID. The div's ID can be used in the code behind file and you can insert some inner HTML.

If you want to get the information without doing a full post-back you will have to have a handler and an AJAX call to the handler from the page. JQuery has a nice AJAX method and creating an API in .NET 4 is the easiest way of creating the handler.

On a side note, you could probably put both Joe and Sue into one table  if they have the same data, and then add another column indicating whether the data relates to Joe or Sue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how to retrieve data from a database and display it in a table (the ASP.NET way, the way you're doing it is possible but takes much more work). If you use the DataSource adapters and asp.net controls to display your data, you will save yourself a lot of time, because often you can display your data with writing any code at all. I did not write any HTML or C# backend code, it was all drag, drop, and mouse clicks...

**Database**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [People]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]